# Terminating other python script with python

Tags: python

Sorry, If I'm a little bit unclear.

I'm writing a module with python, and its basic functions must be `run` or `shut`, which runs or terminates other specified python scripts correspondingly.

`Run` is realised by `os.popen()`, but I did not manage to find any possible realisation for `shut` command. Is there any built-in function in python, which allows you to terminate other scripts?

Comment: Why don't you keep a reference to your process when you call it in `run()` and then just kill it in `shut()`?

Comment: @zwer, What do you mean by reference?

Comment: Use `some_var = subprocess.Popen(["your","command","here"])` on `run()` (make sure `some_var` is globally available) and then `some_var.kill()` when calling `shut()`.